# Динамическое содержимое на страницах битрикса

Tags: битрикс, php, cms

Привет!  
Нужно сделать, чтобы на странице выводились, к примеру, автомобиль, описание, а справа - характеристики: мощность, объём двигателя и т.д. Это можно сделать просто страницей и постоянно правый блок с характеристиками верстать. Но это безумно неудобно. Хотелось бы сделать так: чтобы была кнопка типа "Добавить машину", там вводишь характиристики (заранее уже созданы кастомные поля), и машина появлялась в каталоге.  
Через какую функцию это делается? Я думаю, надо дейстовать через инфоблоки, я прав? Просто хочу сделать всё по стандартам.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Доброго времени суток, [[@iproger](/users/1720/iproger)](/users/1720/iproger). Прочитал Ваш вопрос и создалось ощущение, что вы мало ознакомились с документацией Битрикса, раз даже задаете такие вопросы:

> Через какую функцию это делается?
> Я думаю, надо дейстовать через
> инфоблоки, я прав?

Ответ такой мой. Конечно, лучше всего делать через инфоблоки. [Ссылка на документацию инфоблоков](https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/learning/course/index.php?COURSE_ID=43&CHAPTER_ID=04610&LESSON_PATH=3913.4610). Если Вы внимательно прочитаете все, что там написано, то, думаю, сразу поймете, как оптимально сделать это. Поля-характеристики машины скорее всего будут пользовательскими полями, потому прочитайте [про работу с инфоблоками средствами API](https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/learning/course/index.php?COURSE_ID=43&CHAPTER_ID=04797&LESSON_PATH=3913.4610.4797).

Можете еще поискать видеоуроки по Битриксу, при работе с инфоблоками, чтобы понять лучше, как выводить данные. Поисковики Вам в помощь.

Comment: Я сделал через properties у инфоблоков, всё чётко, спасибо! Читать документацию, прежде чем что-то делать, - задача не из простых, я по ходу читаю, когда что-то надо, я ищу, как это сделать в битриксе, нашёл про инфоблоки, но решил уточнить здесь, вдруг что-то более подходящее будет, спасибо!